# protocols to buying or licensing a patent in its pending state

Tags: patents

For large corporations, what is the standard protocol for their due diligence when they have decided that a patent in its pending state is worth buying or licensing?

Do they hire lawyers to perform extensive prior art patent searches in order to produce a legal opinion of whether the pending patent will be allowed in the end? And if the opinion is that it will be allowed, then they will go forward to pursue the deal.

Specifically, in the case of Molly Metz https://usinventor.org/mollymetz-thejumpropequeen/, do you think that the corporation, Rogue, did the patent search and decided that this patent could be invalided by PTAB, which explains their decision to use her idea without licensing it from her?

Comment: The linked-to article says companies started making and selling products incorporating her design in China and India. And no mention is made that there were issued patents in either place. Assuming no patents in India or China those companies were *not* infringers. However the company ROGUE Fitness does seemed to have made a business decision to try their luck making money as infringers.

Comment: That is acknowledged. But Rogue is a US company.